# How do I set the background of my panel to a specific image file

Tags: python, wxpython

I am kinda new to wxpython. I wanted to create something like a splash screen with a gauge a whatever but I don't like the way it looks since I only know how to change the background color.
Help me out.

This was my code:

```
class Intro(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, pos=(300, 100), size=(350,350),style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('Purple')
```

Well that was part of it.

Comment: No, no, no. Sorry. This is not a place to ask for tutorials or 'recipes' for frameworks or libraries. Please, see the [wxPython API documentation](https://docs.wxpython.org/) (which was the top result when searching for 'wxpython docs').

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `panel.SetBackgroundColour('Purple')` try:

```
panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,0,255))
```

Make sure you [read the docs](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.SetBackgroundColour), particularly concerning is this note:

> Notice that as with SetForegroundColour , setting the background colour of a native control may not affect the entire control and could be not supported at all depending on the control and platform.

Using `SetBackgroundColour` is probably not the best way to achieve what you are after. I would suggest taking a look at the ["wxPython Docs and Demos"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/3.0.2.0/) to get some ideas, you can also easily modify and run the examples to test things out. Perhaps see the 'Advanced Splash Demo'.